# Pointer + int vs point - int

Tags: c, memory, pointers

I have some memory and I try to allocate it in several pieces.
So I have a linked list. Each node keeps track of the size the allocated piece of memory is and the next node.

When I return the pointer to the requester, I return a pointer right after this node ends (say return newNode + sizeOf(node)) because the requester needs just the memory to use.

The problem is when I try to free it by changing the node. When myFree is called with a pointer and I do pointer - sizeOf(node) to get to the node, it doesn't work.

What am I doing wrong?

I don't think it's useful but here's some code:

```
#define HEADER(24)
printf("Original pointer %-10p\n", pointer);
head *toUse = pointer + HEADER;
printf("Pointer to memory to be used %-10p\n", toUse);
printf("Trying to read the header again %-10p\n", toUse - HEADER);
```

The first and third printf gives me different addresses. That's the problem.

As for testing, I just allocate one piece of memory at the beginning and it still doesn't work.

Comment: If you are allocating in several chunks, it is possible that your chunks are not next to each other, so pointer-sizeof(node) does not necessarily put you at the beginning of the previous node.

Comment: I don't think that's valid C, the `#define` is wrong.

Comment: @Mat: It's not, a space is needed between `HEADER` and `(24)`.

Comment: You don't understand pointer arithmetic.  `pointer + HEADER` and `toUse - HEADER` will have different results based on the types of toUse and pointer.  Show the code that defines those types.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In C, `(pointer + n)` is equivalent to `&pointer[n]` ... that is, the index counts the items the pointer points to, not bytes. If you want a byte offset, use `((char*)pointer + n)`. But in your case you don't need a byte offset; instead of

```
return newNode + sizeof(node);
```

you can just do

```
return newNode + 1;
```

or

```
return &newNode[1];
```

Although you probably want to cast those to `(void*)` if you're returning a pointer to something that the caller can use as any type. To get back to the original node from the `(void*)` pointer, use either `(node*)vp - 1` or `(node*)((char*)vp - sizeof(node))`.

Also,

```
#define HEADER(24)
```

won't compile because it resembles a function-like macro; you need at least one space between the macro name and the left parenthesis (or omit the parentheses).

Answer (score 1):

You haven't given us enough code to solve the problem.  However, I can take a guess.

Show us the declaration of `pointer`.  I am  guessing that it is *not* `head *pointer;`.  Pointer arithmetic takes the type of the pointer into account.

When you (for example) add `1` to a pointer to `int` the pointer is incremented by `1 * sizeof int` bytes.  If the type were `short` then it would be incremented by `1 * sizeof short` bytes.  Not necessarily the same thing.

So, if `pointer` is (again, for example) declared as `char *pointer` then adding `HEADER` to it increments the pointer by `HEADER` (`24`) bytes (because `sizeof char` is always `1`).  However, when you later subtract `HEADER` from `toUse`, which is of the type `head*`, it is decremented by `HEADER * sizeof head` bytes.  Again, not the same thing.

Answer (score 0):

Could use some more code to be sure here... but I'm going to throw this by you. You said:

`have some memory and I try to allocate it in several pieces. So I have a linked list. Each node keeps track of the size the allocated piece of memory is and the next node.`

So I'm guessing you're creating nodes, and `malloc()`'ing them some memory, then trying to do something like:

```
ptr_to_next_node = ptr_to_current_node+sizeof(node);
```

Well, that doesn't work. You can't do pointer arithmetic on linked lists because it's not contiguous memory. The reason that pointer arithmetic works on arrays is because the memory that you're getting is going to be continuous:

```
 char array [0][1][2][3]
             ^  ^  ^  ^
             |  |  |  +----------0x86C00004
             |  |  +-------------0x86C00003
             |  +----------------0x86C00002              
             +-------------------0x86C00001

 linked_list 

    +-------+        +-------+        +-------+
    | node1 |        | node2 |        | node3 |
    | next---------->| next---------->| next---------->NULL
    +-------+        +-------+        +-------+
    (0x86C0001)      (0x86C000A)      (0x86C00BC)
```

OK, so the values in memory might not make the most sense, but you can see the point I'm trying to illustrate here. Arrays are `sizeof(type)` apart from one another, the memory you allocate to your nodes could pretty much be anywhere, we can't just add an offset, that's why they have pointers to `next`.

If you want to be able to jump back and forth you need to add pointers forward `next` and backwards `prev`.

Comment: Yes, I understand. I wasn't using malloc, but my pointers were different type. I was able to fix it.